# WPF C# app crashes in windows 11 with Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

i am developing an app in Visual Studio 2022 .net core 3.1 it works great in Windows 10 and Windows 11, one of the requirements is to take pictures with a WebCam, i bought one to the machine with windows 11 and for my surprise the system is halted when i use the window for that camera, close it and open it again.

this is the code of the window :

```
    <Window x:Class="ServicioTecnico.Vistas.VentanaFotosService"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServicioTecnico.Vistas"
       xmlns:xamlhost="clr- namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost;              assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Camera Viewer">

    <Grid>
        <xamlhost:WindowsXamlHost x:Name="XamlHost"/>
    </Grid>
   </Window>
```

debugging, i discovered that the problem is in the Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.XamlHost i left the code empty, without anything and the problem appears when i close the window and try to open it again, the first time, all of the controls of the window works great, but once closed, when i try to open it again, all the program closes, the faillure is appearing in Windows 11 in Windows 10 works great.

in the code behind there is only the InitializeComponent(), nothing else, i appreciate any help, i already tried to create the WindowsXamlHost in codebehind and the problem persists, if i comment this line, the problem dissappear <xamlhost:WindowsXamlHost x:Name="XamlHost"/>

Comment: Have you tried with classic .NET (say, 4.7.2) and/or later version of .NET Core?

Comment: XamlHost uses the "Xaml Islands" technique to host a UWP control in WPF or WinForms. It requires specific modifications to your WPF/WinForms project settings. Did you make sure that you followed all of Microsoft's instructions on modifying your WPF app to properly host using XamlHost? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands

Comment: Thanks Tam, yesterday i worked with the procedure that you answered (just a new project to test it) and had the same result, since that, i changed all the camera functions and methods to access the camera  and used Aforge with just an <image/>, now it works in Windows 11 and Windows 10.